Animated blob keeps drifting off the mouse
I have a spotlight to have on the background of my website. It essentially shows through a dark grey layer to show a gradient on the background layer. I really want the circle to be morphing as I'm moving the mouse around, but right now it's deviating off the center of where the mouse is. I was hoping for the blob to stay centered on the mouse like it is in this example. When I run my code, the rotating looks fine at first, but once I continue to move my mouse, the blob moves away from my mouse and rotates even off the screen before returning to my mouse. But in the example, the blob stays on track with the mouse movement and if there is no movement the blob stays stationary despite continuing to rotate. I'm wondering if it's because the background layer is a rectangle and how I can fix it? Thank you!
Here is my code!


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const blob = document.getElementById("blob");

  window.onpointermove = event => {
    const {
      clientX,
      clientY
    } = event;

    blob.animate({
      left: `${clientX}px`,
      top: `${clientY}px`
    }, {
      duration: 2500,
      fill: "forwards"
    });
  };
});
body {
  background-color: #222020;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

#gradient-color {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: radial-gradient(50% 123.47% at 50% 50%, #00ff94 0%, #720059 100%), linear-gradient(121.28deg, #669600 0%, #ff0000 100%), linear-gradient(360deg, #0029ff 0%, #8fff00 100%), radial-gradient(100% 164.72% at 100% 100%, #6100ff 0%, #00ff57 100%), radial-gradient(100% 148.07% at 0% 0%, #fff500 0%, #51d500 100%);
  background-blend-mode: screen, color-dodge, overlay, difference, normal;
}

#blob {
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  overflow: visible;
  background-color: white;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}

#blob::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 200vw;
  height: 200vh;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #000;
}

#blob::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 34vmax;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #fff;
  animation: rotate 20s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: rotate 20s infinite;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -ms-border-radius: 50%;
  -o-border-radius: 50%;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
  from {
    rotate: 0deg;
  }
  50% {
    scale: 1 1.5;
  }
  to {
    rotate: 360deg;
  }
}

@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    rotate: 0deg;
  }
  50% {
    scale: 1 1.5;
  }
  to {
    rotate: 360deg;
  }
}

#blur {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  backdrop-filter: blur(12vmax);
}
<div id="gradient-color"></div>
<div id="blob"></div>
<div id="blur"></div>




You take the mouse coordinates, hand them "to CSS", CSS then scales and rotated those into new coordinates, finally your blob is drawn at those transformed coordinates (i.e. not where the mouse cursor is).

I see, since I was following the example I have linked I guess I thought it would function the same way in the code. Do you know how I can fix it? Thank you for your comment ◡̈

I simplified and cleaned up a lot of your css and added a little to your javascript.

The main changes were including an offset to mouse coordinates in javascript.
Removing the transforms and left/top positions in your css.



document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const blob = document.getElementById("blob");

  window.onpointermove = event => {
    const {
      clientX,
      clientY
    } = event;


    // EDIT
    // An offset to match the css 34vmax
    const offset = (innerHeight < innerWidth ? innerHeight : innerWidth) * 0.34
    blob.style.left = `${clientX - offset}px`
    blob.style.top = `${clientY - offset}px`
  };
});
body {
  background-color: #222020;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#gradient-color {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: radial-gradient(50% 123.47% at 50% 50%, #00ff94 0%, #720059 100%), linear-gradient(121.28deg, #669600 0%, #ff0000 100%), linear-gradient(360deg, #0029ff 0%, #8fff00 100%), radial-gradient(100% 164.72% at 100% 100%, #6100ff 0%, #00ff57 100%), radial-gradient(100% 148.07% at 0% 0%, #fff500 0%, #51d500 100%);
  background-blend-mode: screen, color-dodge, overlay, difference, normal;
}

#blob {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  overflow: visible;
  background-color: white;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}

#blob::before {
  content: "";
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: #000;
}

#blob::after {
  content: "";
  width: 34vmax;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  animation: rotate 20s infinite;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    rotate: 0deg;
  }
  50% {
    scale: 1 1.5;
  }
  to {
    rotate: 360deg;
  }
}

#blur {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  backdrop-filter: blur(12vmax);
}
I lost track of all the changes I made, but I cleaned up and simplified a lot of the css and added an offset to the coordinates your Javascript.

The big changes were:
  1. getting rid of the left, right and transform in blob::after
  2. using an offset on your coordinates in the Javascript
<div id="gradient-color"></div>
<div id="blob"></div>
<div id="blur"></div>




You may like to add in a verbal explanation - pointing out what was wrong in the original and how this snippet corrects it so future readers know (they won't necessarily read all the comments on the original post).

Thanks @AHaworth. I had typed up the description, somehow it disappeared  before I clicked save. :-(
